# Is this a Circular database references/foreign key?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, circular-reference

I am beginner in database design. This is the system that I have to design.

A Company have Employees that works for them.
A Company have Clients that they do business with.
A Company have Tasks they could do for Clients.
A Task have Milestones that have to take place before task is finish.
An Employee have Milestones to finish for the Tasks.

So my database design looks like this:

**Company**
CompanyID     PK

**Client**
ClientID      PK
CompanyID     FK

**FixedTask**
FixedTaskID   PK
CompanyID     FK

**Milestones**
MilestoneID   PK
FixedTaskID   FK

**Employee**
EmployeeID    PK
CompanyID     FK

**TaskPlanning**
TaskPlanningID PK
EmployeeID     FK
ClientID       FK
MilestoneID    FK

Can anyone tell me if this is circular reference? And if so, how can I fix it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Is it circular? No, it's not.

You'd see that *instantly* if you drew a diagram of the situation, plugging in the foreign key references:

```
               +--------------+
    +--------> |   Company    | <--------+
    |          +--------------+          |
    |                 ^                  |
    |                 |                  |
+--------+     +--------------+     +----------+
| Client |     |  FixedTask   |     | Employee |
+--------+     +--------------+     +----------+
    ^                 ^                  ^
    |                 |                  |
    |          +--------------+          |
    |          |  Milestone   |          |
    |          +--------------+          |
    |                 ^                  |
    |                 |                  |
    |          +--------------+          |
    +----------| TaskPlanning |----------+
               +--------------+
```

Hence, no need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As [paxdiablo has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9925974/533120), this is not a circular reference.

It is, however a **"diamond-shaped"** dependency, meaning you don't just have "splitting", but also have "merging" of lines that denote the relationships between tables. In other words, this is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) but not a tree.

There is nothing inherently to "fix" in diamond-shaped dependencies, however some DBMSes (notably, MS SQL Server) cannot enforce diamond-shaped relationships declaratively (i.e. through FOREIGN KEY syntax), so you'd be forced to use the triggers instead.